# Синонимизировать метки на тему [кодогенераторы]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки

- [code-generator](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-generator) (3 вопроса)
- [кодогенераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b) (15 вопросов)

Я предлагаю их синонимизировать в сторону метки `генераторы-кода` (её пока нет).

Comment: А почему стоит выбрать итоговой метку, которой ещё нет?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ слишком длинное слово - сразу не прочитаешь.

Comment: Но ведь предложенное - ещё длиннее.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, так ведь *слово* длинное, а в предложенном - два слова.

Comment: Если можем прочитать "синонимизировать", то и с этим справимся :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну так это привычно... )

Comment: Ладно, синонимизируйте как хотите.

Comment: Не надоело синонимизировать всё подряд?)

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard, что делать, кто-то же должен приводить метки в порядок... Кстати, я - лучший автор вопросов с меткой [meta-tag:синонимы-меток]: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba/topusers.

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard не понятно к чему подколка - человек общественно-полезным делом занимается на сайте для общественно-полезной деятельности.

Comment: @Kromster да так, шутка же.

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard Какая-то непонятная шутка, уточните пожалуйста, что именно вызывает насмешку, активность (слишком много работает) или неразборчивость (предлагает синонимизировать что не надо)? =)

Answer (score 2):

Кодогенераторы кажется предпочтительным вариантом:

- люди уже непосредственно ставили эту метку
- она созвучна с английским термином.